# How to set separate states for mapped elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a button for every element in a list using map. However, each button should change that element's enable status independently but right now they share the same enable state. I am not sure what the alternative to hard coding an x amount of states would be so I am wondering if there is a way to either mass produce states for mapped elements or if this can be done through the one state I created while using a different hook.

```js
const [enableS, setEnableS] = useState(true);
const list = [x,y,z]
return (<>
  list.map(() => 
    <button onClick={()=>setEnableS(!enableS)}>Enable/Disable</button>
  )
  </>);
```

Comment: why don't u use an array? instead of just 'true'

Comment: Could you further elaborate on using an array? Do you mean setting a state to an array of true and falses ([t,t,f,f])? If so, the number of elements in the mapped element can be added to or removed. When removing elements would I just match the index of my array with that of state?

Comment: you really got the idea haha, list.map(( item , index ) => ...

Comment: You are using only a single `enableS` boolean state for all buttons. Each button needs its own state. Do you need more help from here?

Answer (score 0):

So your going to need to store the 3 states your looking for separately in an array.

I had a similar scenario and I used an array like this.

```
// To store a series of values in one const useState.
const [form, setForm] = useState([1, 15, 2, 100, 2, 2, 5, 5]);
...
function formCallback(val, index) {
    let newArray = form.map(x => x)
    newArray[index] = val
    //mapped twice to avoid bug.
    setForm(newArray.map(x => x))
    console.log(form)
    }
```

in your scenario I would try

```
const [enableS, setEnableS] = useState([true,true,true]);

function enableSCallback(oldBool, index) {
    let newArray = form.map(x => x)//Holding the values in a temporary array.
    newArray[index] = !oldBool//Adjusting the value you want flipped.
    setEnableS(newArray.map(x => x))//Updating the state with these new values. 
    }
return(
list.map(
(a,b) =>
<button onClick = {enableSCallback(a,b)}</button>
))
```